# Java Serialization with LinkedList

Tags: java, serialization, linked-list

I have to make a linked list Serializable. I understand the basics and have done it successfully, but this has thrown me a curve ball.

The list is made up of Nodes, and the class is derived from an interface. The "data" for each node is left as undefined, meaning any data type or object may be held in it. In the snippet below, the type is "M". How do I specify what data type might be in it to make is Serializable?

I am testing it with storing Strings and Doubles for the time being, but will soon use an object make with a custom class. I can confirm that the list is created correctly.

LinkedList class:

```
public class LinkedMovieList<M extends Comparable<M>>
implements GVLinkedList<M>, Serializable {

private class Node {
    public M data;
    public Node next;

    Node(M element) {
        data = element;
        next = null;
    }

}

Node head, tail;
```

Method of Serializing:

```
private GVLinkedList<Double> allVar, empty;
    allVar = new DoublyLinkedMovieList<>();
    empty = new DoubleLinkedMovieList<>();
    private Double[] doubleList = {1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2, 5.2, 6.2, 7.2, 8.2, 9.2};
    for (Double v : doubleList){
        allVar.insertLast(v);
    }

    File linkedFile = new File("LinkedMovieList.dat");

    try{
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(linkedFile);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        objectOut.writeObject(allVar);  //NotSerializableException thrown

        objectOut.close();

        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(linkedFile);
        ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

        empty = (GVLinkedList<Double>) objectIn.readObject();
        objectIn.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated! I feel it is something simple I should know...
Stack Trace:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: edu.gvsu.cs163.LinkedMovieList$Node
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at edu.gvsu.cs163.Test.LinkedListTestDouble.isSerializable(LinkedListTestDouble.java:321)
```

Comment: So your question is basically: "why do you get a NotSerializableException?", right?. If so, post the complete and exact stack trace of the exception: it tells you what the problem is. My guess is that it says: "NotSerializable: Node". because... the Node class is not serializable.

Comment: Exactly. The Node class is not Serializable. So where do I define what variables to expect?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "where do I define what variables to expect?" If you want to make your list serializable, the class Node must be serializable (i.e. implement Serializable). That's what the error message is telling you.

Comment: That is it, thank you. Stupid mistake and made the wrong class Serializable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `Serializable` interface on `Node` class

```
public class LinkedMovieList<M extends Comparable<M>>
implements GVLinkedList<M>, Serializable {

private class Node implements Serializable {
public M data;
public Node next;

Node(M element) {
    data = element;
    next = null;
}

}

Node head, tail;
```